# Print all the pages in the same level in a book

Tags: 7, navigation, nodes

I am have a book like this

About Us

> --Overview
>   --Vision
>   --Mission

I want there to be menu like this in the left side when the user is in any of there page.

> --Overview
>   --Vision
>   --Mission

Now the links are visible when in About Us page, thats the main parent page. I have spend 2 hours already in google and drupal documentation but no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work out of the box if you add the book navigation block to a region.

EDIT:

Sorry, I didn't realise that I was on on of the book pages so the book block expands in this case but not on non book pages. The way around this is to use [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) and create a menu block that starts at your About Us. Make sure you go into the advanced options of the menu block and select `Expand all children of this tree`.